# How to avoid Many2many duplication in Odoo 13?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

In Odoo 13, when I duplicate a sale order which has invoices linked to it, the new sale order has no invoices linked to it, which is OK.

The problem is that in my case, there are a lot of third party apps installed in my database, and here, when I duplicate a sale order, the new one has the same invoices linked to it than the source one, which obviously is a wrong behavior.

I am trying to fix it. So first I checked even through the interface that the following fields have `copy=False`:

- The *Many2many* field `invoice_lines` from the model `sale.order.line`.
- The *Many2many* field `sale_line_ids` from the model
  `account.move.line`.

Both seem to be OK, with `copy=False`. Why is this happening then? I've also modified the  code to break the program if they are modified in `create` or `write` ORM methods of both models, but they aren't.

Any ideas of how can I locate the guilty code?

Comment: sale.order relates to account.move using its field invoice_ids. Have you checked that  this field: invoice_ids has copy=false too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem: one of the multiple third party apps installed on the database adds a new Many2many field on `sale.order` pointing to `account.move`. This field has not `copy=False`. It shouldn't affect to sale order invoices link, but it does because the app also overwrites de method `_get_invoiced()` from `sale.order`, to add the value of that M2M field to the original `invoice_ids`. The combination of both actions is the problem.

I was able to fix it just adding a `copy=False` to that third party app new field. The problem was also fixed if I commented the `_get_invoiced()` overwrite, but I've chose the first option to preserve what that app does.

These are the reasons why checking `sale.order` `copy()` method or checking `copy` attribute on original fields gave no clues.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a chance to find an inherited `copy` method in one of your third party custom modules. It should be on `sale.order` model because that's where the duplication happened. Try investigating from there.

Comment: +1 because it's a good answer and I forgot to write that I had already checked modifications on SO copy method. The weirdest fact is that with the same code in my computer (and my work colleague's one) the behavior is fine, but in others the behavior is wrong, which is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

sale.order relates to account.move using its field invoice_ids.

Maybe the original field invoice_ids (official addons) has been overridden in one of your third party module with copy=true ?

The original is located in addons/sale/models/sale_order.py:

```py
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _name = 'sale.order'
    
    #...
    invoice_ids = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='account.move',
        string="Invoices",
        compute='_get_invoiced',
        search='_search_invoice_ids',
        copy=False)
```

To investigate the inherited models, you could inherit sale.order in one of your custom module and override the def copy. And Then use the "Step into" command of the (Pycharm-)Debugger to track the other possible overridden def copy in the other custom modules :

```py
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    
    def copy(self, default=None):
        # put a DEBUG break point before the following line:
        res_super = super(SaleOrder,self).copy(default=default)
        return res_super
```

Comment: +1 thank you for your answer, it has a right logic, but finally I've found the solution, which was a bit more complex to find for a person which has not these specific apps installed.